# Robot Suite Setup/Teardown

Tags: robotframework

How can we keep accessible the Library variables through out test suite

```
*** Settings ***
Library ClientConnection

# This works
Test Setup       Connect Client 
Test Teardown    Disconnect Client

# while this doesnt
Suite Setup   Connect Client
Suite Teardown   Disconnect Client

***Keyword***
Connect Client 
    Connect ${PARAM1} ${PARAM1}  #function are specified in Lib ClientConnection

Disconnect Client 
    Disconnect #function are specified in Lib ClientConnection

*** Tests Cases ***
Test1:
   SendMsg #function are specified in Lib ClientConnection depends on object initialized in connect
```

Comment: That depends on how `ClientConnection` is defined. Does it set `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE`?

Comment: No its not defined with ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE

Comment: Thanks Bryan for quick help, setting ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE solved the problem